# deb file working fine in version 16.04 does not in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, deb

This [deb file](http://toolbox.uma.es/download/toolbox_latest.deb) installs an open source program and all related packages. It's been tested in Ubuntu 16.04, Lubuntu 16.04, Stretch and other Debian-baed distros. But after having been tried in Lubuntu 18.04, it failed to install some of the dependencies, that have been verified to be in the repository, and can be installed one by one.

This is how the deb file is recommended to be installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo dpkg -i toolbox_latest.deb
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent ... 
$ sudo apt-get -f install
  Setting up [dependencies]
  ...
```

and these are the packages referred in the deb file:

```
Depends: octave (>=4.0.0), liboctave-dev (>=4.0.0), make (>=4.1-6), geany (>=1.27), geany-plugin-py (>= 1.27+dfsg-2), python (>= 2.7.11-1), python-gtk2 (>= 2.24.0), mlterm (>= 3.5.0), libsixel-bin (>= 1.5.2-2), imagemagick (>= 8:6.8.9.9-7), mercurial (>= 3.7.3), rlwrap (>= 0.41), wmctrl (>= 1.07-7), xautomation (>= 1.09-1), mplayer (>= 1.2.1), libcanberra-gtk-module (>= 0.30), xbitmaps (>= 1.1.1-2), texlive-latex-base (>= 2015.20160320-1), texlive-extra-utils (>= 2015.20160320-1), texlive-latex-extra (>= 2015.20160320-1), texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2015.20160320-1ub), gnome-themes-standard (>= 3.18.0), texlive-lang-korean (>= 2015.20160223-1)
```

After the installation on a fresh Lubuntu 18.04, it is verified that Octave, Geany, texlive and other minor packages have not been installed.

Update: After some search, found that package `geany-plugin-py` is no longer in the [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geany-plugin-py) for 18.04. Is there any way to fetch it from the repository of a previous version? (16.04 does include it)

Comment: `dpkg` does not install dependencies unless you specifically tell it to.  If you want this to occur you use `apt` to install the pre-downloaded .deb file (It can download, or install a local file when given a path to the .deb). `apt` has the capacity to download dependencies and will thus do it. `dpkg` just aborts install.  The packages exist (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=octave) which shows it's in 'universe', so do you have 'universe' installed?  (my guess is yes given lubuntu), so use `apt` to install it, or install the list of deps at the same time as toolbox_latest.deb

Comment: Have tried `sudo apt install ./toolbox_1.0-752.deb`, it informs of the broken dependencies and suggests using `apt --fix-broken install`, after which 6 packages (out of the 16 needed) were said to be installed. `geany`, `octave` and others remained uninstalled.

Comment: We can help more if you provide the full error messages, and not just summary. I looked up `octave` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=octave) and 18.04 uses 4.2.2 which is >=4.0.0 from your first post; so something is wrong with your sources. You could try `apt-cache policy octave` to see where you're getting it from (are you hiding it because it'll show mint or other off-topic flags?) or at a minimum you simply don't have 'universe' enabled (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geany) but as already stated, it should be installed with lubuntu.

Comment: Why did you error indicate the `geany` found was <1.27 when the 18.04 source provides 1.32-2?  The `apt-cache policy` commands I've already alluded to will help there, as to me your issue seem like bad sources. (/etc/apt/sources.list or sources.list.d/*).  To help more I'd need more of your error messages  (*I've added this for your understanding; at least that was my hope*)

Comment: @guiverc , you're right. the error reports were in Spanish, that's the reason, they wouldn't help much. I'll try an English version and will provide them here. thanks.

Comment: *Thanks; your english was so good it never occurred to me it could be because of another language being used... My apologies.*